# One JLabel is stuck in corner of frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

I have a label (in my program called thirdlabel) that remains stuck on the bottom left side of the frame when all other labels seem to work fine. I have tried repaint(), pack(), and etc. This is very interesting and I'd like to get to the bottom of why it isn't working.
So far my guess is that it is related to the LayoutManager (since I used setLayout(null)).

IMAGE EXAMPLES:
[image: code1]
[image: code2]

CODE

```
 public void secondframe() {
        JFrame newframe = new JFrame("newframe");
        //newframe.pack(); this is not necessary
        newframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        newframe.setTitle("Personal Information");
        newframe.setSize(1000, 1000);
        newframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Container secondContainer = getContentPane();
        JTextField firstnameArea = new JTextField("");
        JTextField middleinitialArea = new JTextField("");
        JTextField lastnameArea = new JTextField("");
        JLabel firstname = new JLabel("First Name");
        JLabel middleinitial = new JLabel("Middle Initial");
        JLabel lastname = new JLabel("Last Name");
        JLabel lastname2 = new JLabel("Last Name");
        secondContainer.setLayout(null);
        firstnameArea.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 20);
        middleinitialArea.setBounds(400, 100, 50, 20);
        lastnameArea.setBounds(780, 100, 150, 20);
        firstname.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 20);
        middleinitial.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 20);
        lastname.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 20);
        lastname2.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 20);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(firstnameArea);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(middleinitialArea);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(lastnameArea);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(firstname);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(middleinitial);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(lastname);
        newframe.getContentPane().add(lastname2);
        repaint();
        newframe.setVisible(true);
```

As you can see, I created a new label (fourthlabel) and it works fine. I am using EclipseIDE.

Comment: *my guess is that it is related to the LayoutManager (since I used setLayout(null)).* - the issue is that you are NOT using a layout manager. A null layout is NOT a layout manager. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples. You can also nest panels with different layouts to achieve your desired layout. Layout managers force you to think logically about how to display components. Ultimately it will lead to easier to maintain code.

Comment: @camickr I am a beginner with Layout Managers but I wanted my program to be in specific locations and figured the layout managers may prevent me from doing that. After looking at those examples, it seems like they are more for buttons (and I don't see anything about setting specific bounds). What I need (based off your link) is closest to the SpringLayout(SpringForm). Is this feasible?

Comment: I have no idea what you want you layout to look like. All I see is labels displayed all over the place with no apparent logic and random spacing. As I stated you are NOT forced to use a single layout manager. You can group components logically on different panels if necessary. A GridBagLayout is easier to use than a SpringLayout and can easily be use to display components in a grid like pattern. And why would you give your "text fields" variable names with "text area". There is a JTextArea component so that is very confusing.

Comment: @camickr I have renamed the variables (please revisit the code). lastname2 label works fine, lastname does not. That is my question.

Comment: *That is my question.* - and my answer is to take the time to learn layout managers. Hardcoding values for the size/location of components is error prone as you have discovered. *it seems like they are more for buttons* - then you don't understand layout managers, which is why you actually need to read the tutorial and download the working examples and play with them.  A layout manager is for any component. The examples just show the concept of how the layout manager positions the components. You can use any component of combination of component.

Comment: @camickr I see, so I was correct that the error is from the setLayout(null). I need to use an actual layoutmanager to get this to work correctly. Thanks for letting me know! I'm going to read the link you referred me to and use one of the layout managers.